# Placing checkers on an m x n board

Tags: combinatorics

> What is the maximum amount of checkers you can place on an $m \times n$ checkerboard such that no four checkers make a rectangle parallel to the rows and columns?

The square colors don't matter; it is essentially a grid. Also the checkers are all indistinguishable.

I tried looking at the problem row by row, but this devolved into too many cases. I've also looked at small values of $m$, but couldn't get anywhere.

It seems that if there are a lot of rows, the optimal way is to place 2 checkers for the first $\binom{n}{2}$ rows, and then place 1 continuing down the rest. However, when there are relatively few rows, there seems to be a lot of cases regarding how many checkers to place for each row.

Comment: Sorry, I should clarify. The square colors don't matter, it is essentially a grid. Also the checkers are all indistinguishable.

Comment: One way to express this is by inclusion/exclusion.  Is there any special motivation?  I would think an application would also involve specifying the number of checkers used.

Comment: I was thinking about this question, and also the question of what is the maximum number of checkers one can place on a checkerboard such that the condition is satisfied. I was having trouble on that too, perhaps it would be better to start there?

Comment: Sure, it might be an easier problem, but not trivial.  One kind of simplification is to note that having no rectangles is invariant under permutation of rows or columns.

Comment: Sorry, I'm failing to see how that would simplify the problem. Could you please elaborate a little?

Comment: I'm thinking we can impose an order on solutions by asking that the number of checkers in row $i$ is descending  (and also condition the order of columns).  This sort of thing helps to factor out redundancy in counting (or prune the search space in maximizing checkers).

Comment: I edited the problem to be maximizing the number of checkers, as it seems to be more approachable. It seems that if there are a lot of rows, the optimal way is to place 2 checkers for the first $\binom{n}{2}$ rows, and then place 1 continuing down the rest. However, when there are relatively few rows, there seems to be a lot of cases regarding how many checkers to place for each row.

Comment: I suspect combinatorial designs (PBDs) can do better.

Answer (score 4):

**Some simple observations**

Let $\mathscr{C}(m,n)$ be the maximum number of checkers one can place on an $m\times n$ board without any four of them forming a rectangle with sides parallel to the board.  We will refer to $m$ as the number of *rows* and $n$ as the number of *columns*.

The roles of $m,n$ are interchangeable, so the function $\mathscr{C}(m,n)$ is symmetric in the sense that $\mathscr{C}(m,n)=\mathscr{C}(n,m)$.

The function is strictly increasing with either argument:

$$ \mathscr{C}(m+1,n) \ge \mathscr{C}(m,n) + 1$$

and when $m,n \gt 1$ we have:

$$ \mathscr{C}(m+1,n+1) \ge \mathscr{C}(m,n)+ 3 $$

For smallish values of $m$ we can work out the maximum number of checkers:

$$ \mathscr{C}(1,n) = n \; ; \; \mathscr{C}(2,n) = n+1 $$

and if $m \ge \binom{n}{2}$ the exact maximum can be reached:

$$ \mathscr{C}(m,n) = \binom{n}{2} + m $$

by placing two checkers on each of $\binom{n}{2}$ rows and one checker on each of the remaining rows (if any).

The challenge is then to obtain good estimates for the intermediate cases, especially when $m,n$ are approximately equal.

**Partial pairwise block designs**

Consider an $m\times n$ incidence matrix with $1$'s in place of checkers on a grid, otherwise $0$'s.  In this way we define a [combinatorial design](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combinatorial_design), not necessarily uniform, with the rows representing $m$ blocks (lines) and the columns representing $n$ varieties (points).

The requirement that no rectangle is formed by the checkers amounts simply to the condition that no pair of column indexes $(j_1,j_2)$ appears in more than one block (row), equivalently no pair of rows (lines) intersect in more than one point.  We do not require that all blocks have an equal number of points (which defines a *uniform* block design) nor that all points are incident with an equal number of lines (a *regular* block design).  Some may find the language of [finite geometries](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_geometry) more appropriate here.

When any two distinct points lie in a unique common block, we have a [pairwise balanced design (PBD)](http://www.maths.qmul.ac.uk/~leonard/designtheory.org/library/encyc/topics/pbd.pdf), for which there are many known results.   A famous result by R. Wilson in the early seventies says such a design exists, when all the blocks are of equal size $k$, for all sufficiently large $n$ provided there are divisibility conditions:

$$ (k-1) \mid (n-1) \;\text{ and }\; k(k-1) \mid n(n-1) $$

Often [finite projective planes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projective_plane) afford especially large such designs, although these are only known to exist for $m=n=q^2+q+1$ for a prime power $q$ (it is an open problem whether projective planes of other sizes exist).

When $q=2$ we have the [Fano plane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fano_plane), which would give us a $7\times 7$ board with *three checkers in each row* (resp. in each column):

$$ \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix} $$

More generally these block designs will have $q+1$ points in each block (and dually each point belongs to $q+1$ blocks), so there is no fixed upper bound on the number of checkers that can share a row or column of the board.

Focusing on the standard $8\times 8$ board, we easily add three more checkers (points) to the $7\times 7$ design above, using an extra row and column.  This gives $24$ checkers on a standard board:

$$ \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix} $$

Further case analysis, easy but tedious, proves this is a maximum.  (Caveat: I did this analysis by hand, and I plan to follow up with code to double check and extend it.)

Comment: I'm curious, was there any intuition behind adding another row of 3? Because I think that at some point $n \times n$ squares would at some point start to use 4 points per block in addition to, and instead of 3. Like the projective planes do give a formula for every $q$, but I'm wondering about the ones in between.

Comment: @qt: As you see, I added two points in the new row and two in the new column, but these overlap so only three points are added in all.  We can always do this to a maximum $m\times n$ board (for $m,n \gt 1$) by taking the "missing" corner of the extra three checkers to be an unoccupied square on the smaller board. This proves increasing the rows *and* columns by one allows at least three more checkers.

Comment: @hardmath Would you like to continue

Comment: @hardmath so what's the bound?

Comment: @hardmath Do we have some expression?

Comment: @ would you like to chat with me

Comment: @Mclalalala Sorry but the chat room I set up is now read only, deleted for inactivity.

Comment: @hardmath how to prove that there is no exact expression

Comment: @Mclalalala: I did not claim "there is no exact expression", only that if we knew an exact expression, it would probably answer some important open problems, such as the [Prime Powers Conjecture](https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Prime_power_conjecture) for finite projective planes.

Comment: @hardmath, would you like to continue

Comment: @hardmath when to continue

Answer (score 1):

A longish comment:

The number of possible rectangles is given by the number of ways to choose two columns times the number of ways to choose two rows. i.e.:
$$\frac{nm(n-1)(m-1)}{4}$$
The number of ways to put $4$ checkers on the board is:
$${nm}\choose{4}$$
Thus, the number of ways to put $4$ checkers on a board without rectangles is just:
$${{nm}\choose{4}} - \frac{nm(n-1)(m-1)}{4}$$
This does not answer your question regarding $k$ checkers on the board