# The maximum amount of checkers placed on an $m \times n$ checkerboard with no rectangles formed

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, combinatorial-designs

What is the maximum amount of checkers you can place on an $m \times n$ checkerboard such that **no four checkers make a rectangle** parallel to the rows and columns? Does there exist **a closed form** for the relationship between **the number of checkers** and **the size of the checkerboard**?

> There are really too many cases and **one specific solution for 4 checkers is below**.
>
> The number of possible rectangles is given by the number of ways to choose two columns times the number of ways to choose two rows. i.e.:
> $$\frac{nm(n-1)(m-1)}{4}$$
> The number of ways to put $4$ checkers on the board is:
> $${nm}\choose{4}$$
> Thus, the number of ways to put $4$ checkers on a board without rectangles is just:
> $${{nm}\choose{4}} - \frac{nm(n-1)(m-1)}{4}$$
> This does not answer your question regarding $k$ checkers on the board

So, what is the generalization of this question? And does there exist **a closed form**? And how to apply some counting skills in this problem and maybe apply some knowledge in the **combinatorics design** like my duplicated questions?

Comment: I'm going to recommend that this Question be merged with the "possible duplicate" you identified (apparently by a different OP), thus preserving the new Answer.  Even the body of this Question is largely a quotation of the Answer on the old Question [posted by nbubis](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/2093180/3111), which deserves attribution.

Comment: you promised that you would continue to answer.

Comment: I'm happy to do more with my answer and to comment on answers by others.  But I'm confused by the two açcounts -- are you the same as the one who asked this before?

Comment: absolutely not, I was another person

Comment: If you'd like do more answer, I'll be very happy

Comment: @hardmath, would you like to do some further work on this question, I'm particularly interested in this question and after few days work, I still have no idea.

Comment: Ok, one point I was hinting at before was that it's a lot to expect any "simple" closed form because if we knew the answer to maximum checkers on a board, we'd also know the answer to a classic open problem in combinatorics, the projective plane [Prime Power Conjecture](https://symomega.wordpress.com/2010/02/26/open-problems-in-finite-geometry-the-prime-power-conjecture/).

Comment: thanks if you can answer my question even just some continued hints

Answer (score 2):

An upper bound on $k$.

Let $X_i$ be the number of checkers placed in row $i$, so we have $\sum\limits_{i=1}^n X_i=k$.

We clearly need $\sum\limits_{i=1}^n \binom{X_i}{2}\leq \binom{m}{2}$.

If $k=qn+r$ then the sum on the left is at least $(n-r)\binom{q}{2}+r\binom{q+1}{2}$.

This allows you to find a bound on $k$, I don't know when this bound is sharp though, it is sharp in the case in which a $(m,k/n,3)$-design exists. And possibly in some other cases, in which the largest value of $k$ that satisfies $(n-r)\binom{q}{2}+r\binom{q+1}{2}$ gives us a value strictly larger than $\binom{m}{2}$.

Comment: what is this mean (m,w/n,3) design, and can you give me some detailed explanation, thank you.

Comment: Because I am not very familiar with combinatorics design.

Comment: When your $w$ (the $m$ of Question statement) is at least $\binom{n}{2}$, then the maximum number of checkers is $\binom{n}{2} + m$ by having $\binom{n}{2}$ rows with two checkers and the rest of the rows one checker apiece.

Comment: I have no idea why I wrote a $w$ variable, I never use it. My $m$ is the same $m$ as in the problem.

Comment: @hardmath thank you${}{}{}{}$

Comment: @hardmath would you like give me a formal proof that there is no expression existed.